# Visual Studio 2015 Editor Exception with no Intellisense in ASP.NET MVC Page

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

When i write code and see the **very first intellisense of visual studio session** in ASP.NET MVC PAGE.

I get an error about the exception has been logged to activity xml file.
I have checked and found the following exception there logged.

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the
>   path
>   'C:\Users\shana\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Extensions\ersr2sv2.l3w\html\schema\schemas\aurelia.png'.
>   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share) at
>   System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.SetupDecoderFromUriOrStream(Uri
>   uri, Stream stream, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, Guid& clsId,
>   Boolean& isOriginalWritable, Stream& uriStream, UnmanagedMemoryStream&
>   unmanagedMemoryStream, SafeFileHandle& safeFilehandle) at
>   System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateFromUriOrStream(Uri
>   baseUri, Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions,
>   BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, RequestCachePolicy uriCachePolicy,
>   Boolean insertInDecoderCache) at
>   System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.FinalizeCreation() at
>   System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.EndInit() at
>   System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage..ctor(Uri uriSource,
>   RequestCachePolicy uriCachePolicy) at
>   Microsoft.Html.Editor.Schemas.Model.SchemaCompletionGlyphService.LoadGlyph(IHtmlSchema
>   schema, String iconName) at
>   Microsoft.Html.Editor.Schemas.Model.SchemaCompletionGlyphService.GetAttributeGroupCompletionIcon(IList`1
>   supplementalSchemas, ImageSource& glyph, String& iconAutomationText)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Html.Editor.Completion.Html.InitialAttributeGroupCompletion.GetEntries(HtmlCompletionContext
>   context) at
>   Microsoft.Html.Editor.Completion.HtmlCompletionSource.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Editor.Utility.GuardedOperations.InvokeExtensionPoint(Object
>   errorSource, Action action)

Comment: What kind of extension is `ersr2sv2.l3w` and have you removed `aurelia.png`?

Comment: i have no idea also i dont have any folder with this name in extensions folder

Comment: Is the extension in the `Visual Studio Application Designer` > `Extensions` tab ?

Comment: do you mean by extension window. I dont see ersr2 extension in that window installed extensions. Where is Visual Studio Application designer ?

Comment: Solution Explorer > Open the project properties  > Application Designer > Extensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the only fix so far is by resetting all user data (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /ResetUserData).

NOTE: You will lose all customizations, e.g. keyboard shortcuts and window layouts if you do this!